# how to use MS_POSITIONING="flowlayout" in aspx page?

Tags: asp.net

I have to navigate from `.asp` page to `.aspx` page.
We are using the iframe concept so that the pages fit in the browser window.
My problem is that when we navigate from the `.asp` to `.aspx` page the contents are pushed down a little and we are using the concept `<body MS_POSITIONING="flowlayout">` in the top inside which we use form concept to fill in the contents.

Could anyone help me how to push the contents to top of the page?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue myself. I simply added `POSITION:absolute; TOP:0px;` in the table tag
like for example:

```
<body MS_POSITIONING="flowlayout">
        <form id="example" method="post" runat="server">
            <table cellSpacing="0" style="MARGIN-TOP:0px;    POSITION:absolute; TOP:0px;"cellPadding="0" width="100%" align="center" border="0">

//content

</table>
</form>
</body>
```

and the website was looking fine.